# Writing to TensorArray in tf.function - OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to get my code to run in graph mode (tf.function). I know it works in eager mode. In graph mode I get this error `` OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Using a symbolic `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature. `` The error is due to writing to the TensorArray.
If anyone understands why this errors occurs, that would be helpful to know.
This is related to my [question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73712761/inaccessibletensorerror-with-tensorarray).

Here is a MWE for reproducing the error message

```
import tensorflow as tf


class AdjointGrad:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    @tf.function
    def gradient(self, n):
        for i in tf.range(n):
            self.model.call_and_sample(i)
        self.model.return_loss()

class AdjointModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loss_mem = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=10)

    def call_and_sample(self, i):
        self.loss_mem = self.loss_mem.write(i, tf.ones((32,2)))

    def return_loss(self):
        return self.loss_mem.stack()

adjointgrad = AdjointGrad(AdjointModel())
adjointgrad.gradient(tf.cast(10, tf.int32))
```

Comment: The exact reason for this error is not clear to me, but please note that this code will never work properly in graph mode -- the python function is only called once to build the graph, and things like attribute assignments (overwriting self.loss_mem) are not supported in Tensorflow graphs (there are other issues like `gradient` not returning anything). I would not be surprised if this actually related to why the error appears. You will have to re-write this significantly, or stick with eager execution.

Comment: @xdurch0 I'm thinking about two fixes: a) have inner function (call_and_sample) return the TensorArray b) write to memory in outer function instead of in call_and_sample. I know for a fact that b) will work as I've done similar in past, wondering if a) would work, and also disappointed the example as shown here does not work.